# Receive files sent by loopj httpclient in asp.net server

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, loopj

I want to save a picture from an Android device to my ASP.NET server.

The code in android is this:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("name", fileName);
try {
    File imageFile = new File(mPath);
    params.put("image", imageFile);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("onStart", "fail to get imagefile");
}

client.get(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
...
}
```

However, i cant seem to get my file on my server using C#.

Can someone please give me an example how to get my file?

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I feel so stupid, it turns out i had to change one word.

from this:

client.**get**(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() { ...

to:

client.**post**(getApplicationContext(), url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() { ...